# VSCode ESlint and React Typescript declaring type gives an error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, eslint

I've created an axios configuration file which should support typing:

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosInstance } from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/api',
  responseType: 'json',
});

export const apiConfig = ({ baseURL, headers }: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosInstance => axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers,
});

export default api;
```

But i kept on getting this annoying error:

```
'AxiosRequestConfig' is defined but never used.eslint(no-unused-vars)
'AxiosInstance' is defined but never used.eslint(no-unused-vars)
```

This is my ESlint configuration file:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jasmine": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "tsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": {
        "node": {
          "extensions": [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"],
          "paths": ["src"]
        }
      }
    },
    "rules": {
        ....
}
```

I'm really wondering as webpack compiles(eslint-loader added) without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by adding the following in the eslint config rules:

```
   rules: {
    ....
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
        2,
        {
            "args": "none"
        }
    }
```

This is due to a false negative with typescript and eslint: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/941